# Adding Relational Data to a Class From User Class - Parse & Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, relational-database

I have to classes in parse, one is showing the users and the other is showing tweets. Both of the classes has a username column. However, I need to add a relational data to the tweets class that will include the info of the user class object for each user. I tried lots of codes but I could not make it. The views of my two classes are attached. How would be the swift code that when someone enters a new tweet a relational input will also be created in the tweet class. My current tweet code is as below:

```
    var tweetObj = PFObject(className: "tweets")

    tweetObj["userName"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
    tweetObj["profileName"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.valueForKey("profileName") as! String
    tweetObj["photo"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.valueForKey("photo") as! PFFile
    tweetObj["tweet"] = theTweet
    tweetObj["tweetType"] = 1

    if hasImage == true {

        tweetObj["hasImage"] = "yes"

        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.tweetImg.image)
        let imageFile = PFFile(name: "tweetPhoto.png", data: imageData)
        tweetObj["tweetImage"] = imageFile

    } else {

        tweetObj["hasImage"] = "no"

    }


    tweetObj.save()

    println("tweet!")
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJPq7.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9jsI.png

Comment: Do you mean you want something like `tweetObj["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()`?

Comment: Actually yes, i want the tweet table to have a column that inculeds the whole user table info of the user as an object in one column as relational data.

Comment: tweetObj["user"] = PFUser.currentUser() worked for me, thank you Maury. For the ones who will have the same issue, your have to create a collumn  in parse that has the pointer type. (here it will be the user collumn as pointer).

Comment: It's a little bit of a cheat that it works actually, it's not originally part of the API. But because the API is simply an NSDictionary, there's no reason not to add your own items to it. I do like Cocoa!